# Cannot create edge rule on IBM Edge Analytics

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-iot

I have created gateways and devices but they don't show up when I attempt to create an edge rule.

[attempt to link gateway to rule. no gateway shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72QBb.png)

Answer (score 1):

It is insufficient for a Gateway to exist. It must also be connected and have the edge analytic agent installed.  Please see the docs - https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/edge_analytics.html?pos=2#edge_analytics